# TypeError: Argument given by name "id" and position(2) -- wxPython

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I'm attempting to make tabs in wxPython using the [Notebook](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Notebooks) class. Using the tutorial linked above, I came up with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx

class DeployTab(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DeployTab, self).__init__(self, *args, parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, **kwargs)

        self.sizer = wx.Panel(self)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        deploy = wx.Button(
            self.main_panel, 
            label="test 1",
            size=(250, 100))
        self.sizer.Add(deploy, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=5)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

class ConfigTab(wx.Panel):
    # For now, copy.
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ConfigTab, self).__init__(self, *args, parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, **kwargs)

        self.sizer = wx.Panel(self)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        deploy = wx.Button(
            self.main_panel, 
            label="test2",
            size=(250, 100))
        self.sizer.Add(deploy, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=5)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

class NotebookTabs(wx.Notebook):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(NotebookTabs, self).__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.BK_DEFAULT)

        self.deploy_tab = DeployTab(self)
        self.deploy_tab.SetBackgroundColor("Gray")
        self.AddPage(self.main_tab, "Go!")

        self.options_tab = ConfigTab(self)
        self.AddPage(self.options_tab, "Options")


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.SetSize((300, 250))
        self.SetTitle('Testing')
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

        self.setup_sizers()

    def setup_sizers(self):
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.notebook = NotebookTabs(self.panel)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.notebook, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Layout()

    def on_quit(self, event):
        self.Close()

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    MainWindow(None)
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.pyw", line 72, in main
    MainWindow(None)
  File "test.pyw", line 55, in __init__
    self.setup_sizers()
  File "test.pyw", line 61, in setup_sizers
    self.notebook = NotebookTabs(self.panel)
  File "test.pyw", line 36, in __init__
    super(NotebookTabs, self).__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.BK_DEFAULT)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_controls.py", line 3147, in __init__
    _controls_.Notebook_swiginit(self,_controls_.new_Notebook(*args, **kwargs))
TypeError: Argument given by name ('id') and position (2)
```

I then changed `NotebookTabs` to the following (simplifying the superclass initialization):

```
class NotebookTabs(wx.Notebook):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(NotebookTabs, self).__init__(self, parent)

        self.deploy_tab = DeployTab(self)
        self.deploy_tab.SetBackgroundColor("Gray")
        self.AddPage(self.main_tab, "Go!")

        self.options_tab = ConfigTab(self)
        self.AddPage(self.options_tab, "Options")
```

...and got the following error message:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.pyw", line 72, in main
    MainWindow(None)
  File "test.pyw", line 55, in __init__
    self.setup_sizers()
  File "test.pyw", line 61, in setup_sizers
    self.notebook = NotebookTabs(self.panel)
  File "test.pyw", line 36, in __init__
    super(NotebookTabs, self).__init__(self, parent)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_controls.py", line 3147, in __init__
    _controls_.Notebook_swiginit(self,_controls_.new_Notebook(*args, **kwargs))
TypeError: in method 'new_Notebook', expected argument 1 of type 'wxWindows *'
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I don't seem to be able to identify what's wrong. Can somebody help me identify the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not supposed to pass `self` to `super(NotebookTabs, self).__init__`, `super` takes care of that:

```
super(NotebookTabs, self).__init__(parent)

super(DeployTab, self).__init__(*args, parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, **kwargs)

super(ConfigTab, self).__init__(*args, parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3):

This problem occurs when you pass the same argument in both positional and keyword arguments:

```
def foo(x=10, y=20):
    ...

args = [5]
kwargs = { "x":15 }
foo(*args, **kwargs) # x is passed twice
```

I'm not familiar with wxPython, so I couldn't identify exactly where this is happening, but I'd suggest checking your code where it used `*args` and/or `**kwargs`, since the problem is certainly there.

**Update:** as @Pavel Anossov pointed out, the problem is the duplicated use of `self`:

```
super(NotebookTabs, self).__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.BK_DEFAULT)
```

Called this way, `self` will be the first parameter (`parent`) and `parent` will be the second (`id`). And you're also passing `id` as a keyword argument, hence the error.

Comment: You are the first one who explained the cause for this error. Thanks!